# Proving Cayley formula using Kirchhoff matrix theorem?

Tags: graph-theory, determinant

To count the number of spanning trees of a complete graph of order $n$ one can use [Kirchhoff matrix theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem) and arrive at the exact answer $n^{n-2}$. But in doing so, one should know how to evaluate the determinant of this $n-1\times n-1$ matrix?
\begin{bmatrix}
n-1 & -1  & \cdots & -1 \\ 
 -1& n-1 & \cdots  & -1\\ 
\vdots&\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\ 
 -1& -1  &\cdots  & n-1
\end{bmatrix}
I'm asking an efficient method to calculate the determinant of this matrix.

Answer (score 9):

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
n-1 & -1  & \cdots & -1 \\ 
 -1& n-1 & \cdots  & -1\\ 
\vdots&\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\ 
 -1& -1  &\cdots  & n-1
\end{bmatrix}=nI_{n-1}-\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1&1&\cdots&1\end{bmatrix}=nI_{n-1}-A$$

Now, $\text{rk}A=1$ and $$A\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}n-1\\n-1\\\vdots\\n-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence, $A$ can be diagonalized

$P^{-1}AP=\text{diag}(n-1,0,\ldots,0)$.

Hence $\det(B)=\det(P^{-1}BP)=\det(nI_{n-1}-P^{-1}AP)=\det(\text{diag}(1,n,\ldots,n))=n^{n-2}$

Comment: Here "A can be diagonalized" is due to the algebraic and geometric multiplicities are same, then $P^{-1}$ can be valid. (Detailed reasons see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1414646/1059606)). Otherwise, the geometric multiplicity $\gamma _{A}(\lambda )$ may be smaller than algebraic multiplicity $\mu _{A}(\lambda )$ (one [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Diagonalizable_matrices)). (Notice algebraic multiplicity $\ge$ geometric multiplicity. This is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/458200/1059606))