# Matrix with all 1's diagonalizable or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a followup to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414636/eigenvalues-of-matrix-with-all-1s).

Let $A$ be the $n \times n$ matrix over a field of characteristic 0, all of whose entries are 1. Is $A$ diagonalizable?

Comment: I think that creating a new profile for every separate question is not very welcome here.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is always diagonalisable when the field has characteristic 0 or characteristic $>n$.

Let $e_i$ denotes the vector with a $1$ at the $i$-th position and zeros elsewhere. Let $P$ be the matrix whose first and second columns are respectivelly $\sum_je_j$ and $e_1-e_2$ and whose $j$-th column is $e_2-e_j$ when $j\ge3$. Clearly, the columns of $P$ are eigenvectors of $A$. It is not hard to show that $\det P=(-1)^{n+1}n$. Therefore $P$ is invertible and the aforementioned eigenvectors form an eigenbasis when the characteristic of the field is either $0$ or $>n$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a matrix $P$ that I made up some time ago.  Note that $P$ is not orthogonal, although the columns are pairwise orthogonal.

10:
$$    
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  4  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  5  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  6  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  7  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  8  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  9   
\end{array}
\right).
$$

3:
$$    
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  1  &  -1     \\
  1  &  0  &  2     \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

4:
$$    
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1     \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1     \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3     \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

5:
$$    
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  4    \\
  \end{array}
\right).
$$

The columns of $P$ are of varying lengths; for the 10 by 10 case depicted, lengths $ \sqrt{10}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{6}, \sqrt{12},..$ All that is necessary to make an orthogonal matrix $Q$ out of this is to divide each column by its length. In turn, this tells us that $\det P = \pm n!,$ as $\det Q = \pm 1.$ The result is $Q^T Q = Q Q^T = I$ and $Q^T = Q^{-1}.$ Meanwhile, $Q^T A Q= Q^{-1}AQ$ is diagonal, in this case the diagonal elements are the eigenvalues.

Comment: I'm not sure how this fits the question. Maybe the question changed, but I see no note about this.

Comment: @egreg, given $A$ with all ones, and my $P,$ we get $P^T A P = D$ diagonal. There are two commonly confused types of diagonalization, for general matrices $R^{-1} A R,$ for symmetric matrices $S^T A S.$ The overlap is orthogonal diagonalization, my $Q^T A Q.$ If the OP had followed up with questions in comment, I could have explained.

Comment: @egreg , compare http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395634/given-a-4-times-4-symmetric-matrix-is-there-an-efficient-way-to-find-its-eige  where the OP mistakenly thought he could find the eigenvalues. Either that, or the whole thing was in a numerical linear algebra course, but that was not my impression. I see, it was your answer there that said the eigenvalues were hopeless. Anyway, I like the answer by el.salvador and now know how to do his algorithm, my own way though.

Comment: @egreg, well, anyway, the students here do not really know, is the problems they post, whether a symmetric matrix is being regarded as a linear transformation or as a quadratic form. I am happiest with quadratic forms.

Comment: When I see “diagonalizable”, I always think to eigenvalues.