# Need help to prove this given matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The matrix  given to me is **:**

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&r&r\\r&1&r\\r&r&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Find the values of $r$ for which this is positive definite.
So,I naturally  try to find the determinant of the matrix $$A-xI$$ where $$I$$ is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix.

The determinant is $${(1-x)}^3-2r^2(1-x)+2r^3$$

My idea was that solving this equation $${(1-x)}^3-2r^2(1-x)+2r^3=0$$ for $x$  in terms  of $r$  and keeping in  mind that  *each  value  of $x$ that is the eigen value has to be $\gt 0$ ,* I could find the  required  possibilities  for  $r.$ But the problem here became that I failed to solve this equation.

Please  help  me  solve  the  equation  for $x$  and I think I can  finish the rest  by  myself .

Also, any suggestion  of  a  different  approach  or  different  trick  is  most welcome .

Thank you .

Comment: (A) given a matrix $K$ with all entries equal to $1,$ what are the eigenvalues? (B) what are the eigenvalues of $sK$ for real $s?$ (C) what are the eigenvalues of $sK + tI?$ Here all are square three by three

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way: Let $e=(1,1,1)^T$, then we see that $e e^T$ is positive semidefinite
with one eigenvalue of $3$ (in the direction $e$) and two at zero (on the
subspace $\{e\}^\bot$).

Then we have $A = r e e^T + (1-r) I$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are those
of $r e e^T$ shifted by $1-r$.

Details:

> Since $r e e^T$ has eigenvalues $0, 3r$ we see that $A$ has eigenvalues $1-r, 1+2r$. For these eigenvalues to be positive, we need $1+2r >0$ or $r > -{1 \over 2}$ and $r <1$, so equivalently we need $r \in (-{1 \over 2}, 1)$.

Comment: the  first one has nonzero eigenvalue $3$

Comment: @WillJagy: Thanks for catching that. Bad day.

Comment: I came up with a sort of standard matrix of eigenvectors for the matrix of all ones, all columns eigenvectors and pairwise orthogonal, but integer entries and so not unit length. An orthogonal matrix of eigenvectors can be made just by dividing each column by its length. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414690/matrix-with-all-1s-diagonalizable-or-not/1414925#1414925  You may have seen this before, of course.

Comment: @WillJagy: I haven't; that's pretty, curious and pretty neat! (Also slightly similar to a matrix used to show that Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting can have $2^{n-1}$ element growth.)

Comment: don't think I know your Gaussian example.

Comment: @WillJagy: I misremembered, the matrix used as an example showing the element growth in partially pivoted LU factorisation is of the same form but with all ones on the diagonal, -1 below, zeros above except for the rightmost column of all ones. Still a bad day :-).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Before calculating the determinant directly, add the second and the third row to the first row. Then add a multiple of the first row to the second and third rows to bring the matrix into a particularly simple form from which you'll be able to read the determinant immediately.