# Diagonalization of $ A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & a & a \\ a & a & a \\ a & a & a \end{smallmatrix}\right) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Consider the matrix: $$ A=\left(\begin{matrix} a & a & a \\ a & a & a \\ a & a & a \end{matrix}\right) $$
How to prove whether $A$ is diagonalisable or not. And how to diagonalize it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix with all 1's diagonalizable or not?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414690/matrix-with-all-1s-diagonalizable-or-not)

Comment: What is the standard procedure to find the Eigenelements ?

Comment: $A$ has eigenvalues $3a$, and $0$ of algebraic multiplicity $2$. Since the geometric multiplicity of $0$ eigenvalue is also $2$, the matrix is diagonalizable (assuming over $\mathbb C$ for instance).

Comment: @Dave thanks, is there a way to diagonalize it using elementary operations on rows and colones?

Answer (score 2):

To diagonalize, first notice that $$A\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3a\\3a\\3a\end{bmatrix}$$ so $$u:=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ is an eigenvector of the $3a$ eigenvalue. To find eigenvectors $v,w$ of the $0$ eigenvalue, simply reduce $A$ to its RREF and determine a basis for the kernel. Then we can diagonalize $A$ as $A=P^{-1}DP$ with $$D:=\begin{bmatrix}3a&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ and $P:=\begin{bmatrix}u&v&w\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks, do elementary operations also work to transform it to a diagonal matrix? What I did is this $ A=\left(\begin{matrix} a & a & a \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right) $ but I stopped at this point.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to use elementary operations to do (i.e. what do you mean by "transform it to a diagonal matrix"?).

Comment: I mean using Gaussian elimination, that is using elementary row operations to modify the matrix until we find a diagonal matrix (the same procedure we use to find the inverse of a matrix) In the end we find a diagonal matrix. But is this diagonal matrix $D$ similar to the original matrix $A$ ($A=P^{-1} D P$)?