# How can i get these eigen values of this hard to handle matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'd like to proof that eigen values of this matrix is given by (8-16) and bellow to (8-17), my trouble is about solve p-degree polynomial.
[image]

Comment: if $\rho !=1$ this matrix has rank p not 1.

Comment: your question depends on knowing the matrix with all entries $1$ Call such a matrix $T.$   The eigenvectors are the same;  then $\rho T$ has those eigenvalues multiplied by $\rho.$  Finally, adding $(1-\rho)I$  shifts the eigenvalues by exactly $1-\rho$   Meanwhile, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414690/matrix-with-all-1s-diagonalizable-or-not/1414925#1414925

Comment: $\mathbf{\rho_{pxp}}=\rho.\mathbf{1_{pxp}}+(1-\rho)I_{pxp}$ where $\mathbf{1}=T$. I see ones-matrix on it but i didn't get what you did after that at all, mainly the why $(1-\rho)I$ will increase each eigenvalue by $1-\rho$. I've looked through your link though. That would be more easy to see if $det(A+B)=det(A)+det(B)$

Comment: suppose we have a matrix $M$ where we know the eigenvalues. We take an eigenvector $v$  such that $Mv = \lambda v.$  Then $ (\alpha M + \beta I)v = \alpha Mv + \beta I v = \alpha \lambda v + \beta v = (\alpha \lambda + \beta) v$

Comment: Let $v$ be eigenvector to $\rho_{pxp}$. We have $\rho_{pxp}v=(\rho\mathbf{1}+(1-\rho)I_{pxp})v=\rho\mathbf{1}v+(1-\rho).v=\lambda.v$ so $\rho\mathbf{1}v=\lambda.v-(1-\rho).v$, $\mathbf{1}v=v.(\lambda-(1-\rho))/\rho$ I guess the ones-matrix has a only eigenvalue equals to $p$ so  $(\lambda-(1-\rho))/\rho=p$ with that we can get $\lambda$, $\lambda-1+\rho=p\rho$ so $\lambda=p\rho+1-\rho$ finally i get $\lambda=1+(\rho-1)p$. Now what should i do to get $1-\rho$. I cannot see ones-matrix having more than eigen value different to $0$ but if you wanna stop here since you helped a lot.

Comment: Ok, i see, not ignoring non-null values to eigen values of $\mathbf{1}$ we get $(\lambda-1+\rho)/p=0$ so $\lambda=1-p$