# Parametric Equation of an $(n-2)$-Sphere in n-Dimensional Space on the Hyperplane $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = 0$

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, spheres

Given a circle in a 3D space centered on the plane $x+y+z=0$, its parametric equation can be represented as:

$$
\left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\cos(t) + \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}}\sin(t), -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\cos(t) + \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}}\sin(t), -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\sin(t) \right)
$$

where $t \in [0, 2\pi]$. This equation is derived using two orthogonal unit vectors, $v_1$ and $v_2$, lying in the plane $x+y+z=0$.

However, I am finding difficulties in generalizing this to higher dimensions. Specifically:

> How can one describe a parametric equation for an (n-2) dimensional
> sphere in an n-dimensional space if that sphere is centered on the
> hyperplane defined by $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = 0$?

Any insights or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

p.s. Visualization for better understanding of the circle talked about above:
[image]

Comment: If we have (i) a parametrization of the "standard" $(n-2)$-sphere in the hyperplane $x_n=0$, it suffices to construct (ii) an orthonormal basis of the desired hyperplane, which can be done with Gram-Schmidt. Is that what you're asking, or are you asking about either (i) or (ii)?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang What I'm asking is a parametrization of the centered $(n−2)$
-sphere laying on the hyperplane $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=0$. (By centered I mean the center is the $(0,0,...,0)$ point)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414690/matrix-with-all-1s-diagonalizable-or-not/1414925#1414925

Comment: @WillJagy Sorry, is that related to this question?

Comment: I made up a recipe for this. The columns of the matrix below are pairwise orthogonal.  To get orthonormal you just need to divide each column by its length, which involves a square root. $$    
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1     \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1     \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3     \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$  Ignore the first column, then divide by $\sqrt 2, \sqrt 6, \sqrt {12}$ which are double the triangular numbers. Similar pattern in any dimension

Comment: @WillJagy Oh! I see! But shouldn't they fit into the $ x1+x2+...+xn=0$?

Comment: @Peyman  that is true for columns 2,3,4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the hypersphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is centered at the origin is

$ r^T r = R^2 \hspace{20pt}(1)$

where $r = [x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n]^T $ and $R$ is the radius of the hypersphere.

Now, we have the hyperplane

$ \mathbf{1}^T r = 0 \hspace{20pt}(2) $

intersecting the hypersphere.   Where $\mathbf{1} = [1, 1, \dots, 1]^T $

The first step is find the solution of $(2)$, and this is given by

$ r = V u \hspace{20pt}(3)$

where $V$ is $n \times (n-1)$.  It $k$-column has $-1$ at the top row and $1$ at the $(k+1)$-th row.  So, for example, if $n = 4$, then

$V = \begin{bmatrix} -1 && -1 && -1 \\ 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Now, substitute $(3)$ into $(1)$, you'll get,

$ u^T V^T V u = R^2 $

Note that $V^T V$ is $(n-1) \times (n-1)$.

The next step is to diagonalize $V^T V$ and express it as follows

$ V^T V = P D P^T $

where $P$ is the orthogonal matrix whose columns are the mutually orthogonal eigenvectors of $V^T V$ corresponding to the eigenvalues listed as the diagonal entries of $D$.  It is easy to show that $V^T V$ has one eigenvalue equal to $n$ and the rest of the eigenvalues are $1$.

Now we can write

$ u^T P D P^T u = R^2 $

So that if $ w = D^{1/2} P^T u $ is any vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ of length $R$, then we have

$w^T w = R^2 $

It follows that,

$ u = P D^{-1/2} w $

Finally, substituting back,

$ r = V u = V P D^{-1/2} w $

Note that $w$ is the vector parameter here, and it is just a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1} $ multiplied by the radius of the hypersphere $R$.

Hence,

$ r = R V P D^{-1/2} e $

where $ e \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and $e^T e = 1 $.

For example, if $n = 4$, and $R = 1$, then we can take

$ e = [ \sin t \cos s , \sin t \sin s , \cos t ]^T $

And we will have

$ r = A e $

where $ A = R V P D^{-1/2} $, and is given by

$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && - \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} && - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}} && \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{12}} \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} && - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}} && \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{12}} \\ 0 && \sqrt{ \dfrac{2}{3}} && \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{12}} \end{bmatrix}$

Note that $\mathbf{1}^T A = 0 $, i.e. the sum of the entries of each of the three columns is $0$, and in addition, the three columns are of unit length, and mutually orthogonal to each other.  And therefore,

$ A^T A = I_3 $

From $\mathbf{1}^T A = 0$ it follows that $ \mathbf{1}^T r = 0 $ , i.e $r$ as given above is on the given hyperplane.  And in addition,

$ r^T r = e^T A^T A e = e^T e = 1 $

Hence $r$ is also on the given unit hypersphere.