Find diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A$ is congruent to $D$
Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be  the matrix with all entries equal $1$. Find the signature of $A$ and find a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A$ is congruent to $D$.

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $P(x)=x^{n-1}(x-n)$. So, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $0, n$.
The rank of $A$ is $1$. Since $A$ is symmetric, the real case of inertia law says that there exist a basis $B$ and non-negative integers $p,q$ such that $$p+q=r,$$ $$[f]_B=I_p\oplus (-I_q)\oplus 0_{n-r}$$where $r$ is the rank of $A$ and $p,q$ the number of positive/negative eigenvalues of $A$, respectively. In this particular case, we have one positive eigenvalue and zero negative eigenvalues, so $p=1, q=0,$ and clearly $p+q=1$. The signature of $A$ is $p-q=1$.
Now, regarding the part about finding a congruent matrix I have two candidates.

$D=I_1\oplus (-I_0)\oplus 0_{n-1}$$=$diag$(1,0,...,0)$ here the number of $0$ diagonal entries is $n-1$.

$D=$diag$(n,0,...,0),$ here the number of $0$ diagonal entries is $n-1$ too. This is the matrix with eigenvalues of $A$ on the diagonal.


Is $A$ actually congruent to both of this choices of $D$?

see   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414690/matrix-with-all-1s-diagonalizable-or-not/1414925#1414925

your two versions of $D$ are congruent. Take $E$  as the diagonal matrix with $\sqrt n$  in the $1,1$  position, the other diagonal elements $1.$ So $E=E^T$ Take your first $D$  candidate and find $EDE$

@WillJagy Great. Thanks!
