# Eigenvalues and matrix rank, any relation?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

Is it true to say that matrix rank is equal to the number of eigenvalues different from 0?

If not please give me contradiction example since I didn't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $$ \begin {pmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\\ \end{pmatrix}$$.

This matrix has both Eigen values zero but its rank is one.

Answer (score 0):

The dimension of eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=0$ is the nullspace of $A$ therefore, by rank-nullity theorem, the statement is true only when the geometric and algebraic multiplicity are equal for $\lambda=0$, that is when the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ is not [defective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix).

Refer to the related

- [Finding the rank of the matrix directly from eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1876141/505767)
- [Relation between rank and number of distinct eigenvalues of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146927/505767)