# Finding the rank of a matrix from its eigenvalues without using the rank-nullity theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

I am taking a course in linear algebra, and one of the questions is as follows (not a quote from the questions):

> The matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 4 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $5$ and $-2$, this need not be proven. Find the rank of the matrix $xI - A = \begin{bmatrix} x-1 & -3 \\ -4 & x-2\end{bmatrix}$ for each real number $x$.

I have read other questions such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876141/finding-the-rank-of-the-matrix-directly-from-eigenvalues) which use the rank-nullity theorem. However, this concept has not been introduced yet, which I assume means that it should not be used to solve the problem. Instead, I have only learnt of eigenvalues, eigenvectors, diagonalisation, as well as matrix algebra. The textbook that is being used is *Linear Algebra with Applications* by W. Keith Nicholson and is open source, [available online here](https://lyryx.com/linear-algebra-applications/). This question is asked after having completed chapter 3.3 of the textbook.

I have tried manipulating $A$ into reduced row-echelon form, but I can't seem to be able to do this for all numbers $x$, and I don't quite understand the relationship between ranks and eigenvalues yet.

Comment: The rank of $xI-A$ is at least $1$ because the matrix has at least a non-zero element. The rank is $2$ iff $\det(xI-A)\not=0$ that is when $x\not=5$ and $x\not=-2$

Comment: I'm pretty sure you may know enough to prove the rank-nullity theorem. The proof is quite elementary: Suppose $A \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear. Find a subspace $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mathbb{R}^n = \text{nullspace}(A) \oplus U$. Prove that $A$ is an isomorphism from $U$ to $\text{range}(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $x_0$ is an eigenvaluo of $A$ if and only if $det(x_0I-A)=0$.

With this in mind, $xI-A$ would have maximal rank for any $x$ not being an eigenvalue. In your case, $rank(xI-A)=2$ for $x\ne 5,-2$.

For $x=5,-2$ you know that the rank cannot be 2. But since there is always some nonnull entry in $xI-A$, the rank must be 1.

The argument for rank 2 works for any order of the matrix $A$, but the rank-1 argument only works for 2x2 matrices with a nonnull entry putside the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Collect the (representative) eigenvectors in $\mathbf B$.  The eigenvalues are distinct so the eigenvectors are linearly independent.  Now
$\mathbf BD=  A\mathbf B$
where $D$ has the eigenvalues of $5$ and $-2$ on its diagonal -- which means $D$ is invertible.  So

$2=\text{rank}\big(\mathbf B\big)=\text{rank}\big(\mathbf BD\big)=  \text{rank}\big(A\mathbf B\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(A\big)\leq 2 $
Thus $\text{rank}\big(A\big) = 2$