# Why a simple eigenvalue is regular?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Title says all: I can't understand this basic proof. 
A simple eigenvalue is an eigenvalue with multiplicity algebraic of 1; but why the m. algebraic is equal to the geomtric one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some number $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue, there must be some eigenvector associated with it: $A - \lambda I$ has determinant $0$ so has non-trivial kernel.

On the other hand, there can't be more than one associated eigenvector because the [geometric multiplicity is bounded by the algebraic multiplicity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458189/why-geometric-multiplicity-is-bounded-by-algebraic-multiplicity).

Therefore, the geometric multiplicity is at least 1 and is at most 1: it is exactly 1.