# Rewriting a matrix with respect to new basis depending on geometric multiplicity of eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

Many proofs that the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue cannot exceed the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue use the following idea:

Let the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ be $k$. Then we have $k$ linearly independent vectors $v_1,...,v_k$ such that $Av_i = \lambda v_i$. If we change our basis so that the first $k$ elements of the basis are $v_1,...,v_k$, then with respect to this basis we have
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda I_k & * \\
    0 & B \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

(this came directly from [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458189/why-geometric-multiplicity-is-bounded-by-algebraic-multiplicity))

Could someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: The columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors.

Comment: @amd Thanks for the response! Could you elaborate a bit? I'm a little confused about the change of basis portion and how to think about this in terms of block matrices.